# How do I get around needing administrator privleges, playing Guild Wars 2 on OS X?

Tags: technical-issues, guild-wars-2, macos

During the install, Guild Wars 2 required administrator privileges. Since I didn't want to give them, I installed it to another computer, and moved the files.

When I run it, it again asks for root access. In this case, I can simply cancel, but I get this window:

[image: Guild Wars 2 error screen]

It shouldn't need root, it has no reason to. **Can I get around this issue, without allowing administration privileges?**

Comment: @Timelord64 there's simply no reason to keep it closed. Either you close **all** the questions with [tag:technical-issues] (and then I wonder why we have that tag at all), or this is in-topic.

Comment: I can see your argument. The problem you have is that you are clearly asking for technical support, based off your response to my comment, and your comment on the answer. However, **in the question, itself, you never ask for help one bit**. You ask **why**, which leads to **Developer Intent**. Ill make an edit that I believe fixes the problem. Just roll it back if I have overshot your intent.

Comment: Keep in mind that I am using this edit as a valid reason to reopen, and will have to list the question for closure again, if rejected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a GW2 forum post with some details

https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/support/support/Why-require-root-level-system-authorization

Basically the game needs admin access to update itself because it is writing to the application folder.

Comment: This is odd: moving it to the user's application folder didn't fix this problem…

Comment: You still need admin privileges to write to user application folder.

Comment: I accepted this as a "there is no workaround", because in the end I gave up :/

Comment: Well you can just ignore the client's need to update and only grant it on a controlled basis instead of giving it all the time.  Given it is an entire application, I'm not sure what else you can do so it can update itself.

Comment: It asks just once: then it sets a suid somewhere and it won't ask it any more. And it makes sense. I don't buy the "plz gief me root to update" argument, since every other app does not need that, but I gave up anyway…

Comment: And I gave up since I got random in-game crashes, and I couldn't report them unless I knew everything else was in-order.